# What does the combination "sed tamen" mean?

Tags: word-usage

sed - but
tamen - however, nevertheless

What does these words then mean when placed together? Placing a "but" in front of "however" seems unnecessary to me.

I often see this at the end of "unfinished" phrases, in conversational Esperanto. Most cases are discussions, where the standpoint of the speaker is already known:

Mi komprenas kion vi diras sed tamen...
Estas bela ideo sed tamen...
Mi scias kiom da kostoj ni jam havas, sed tamen...

I've been translating this to "but still" in my head. Is that correct?

Comment: Help with the tags would be appreciated! And also, If anybody has better examples, please edit/comment.

Comment: "Sed tamen" (with and without punctuation) is very common in the Tekstaro, if you need more examples. There's also a short and sweet answer to this question at ReVo.

Answer (score 9):

"But however" does seem odd, but nevertheless ...